# LINQ Group By and select collection

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this structure

```
Customer
 - has many Orders
  - has many OrderItems
```

I want to generate a list of `CustomerItems` via LINQ given a subset of `OrderItems`:

```
List of new { Customer, List<OrderItem> Items }
```

which is a grouping of all the items a Customer has ordered from the subset of items

How can i use LINQ to back track through the order and group by Customer to generate this object?

so far I'm on something like

```
items
 .GroupBy(i => i, i => i.Order.Customer, (i, customer) => new {customer, i})
```

But thats obviously not a List. I'm guessing I need a SelectMany in there somewhere, but could do with some pointers.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

I think you want:

```
items.GroupBy(item => item.Order.Customer)
     .Select(group => new { Customer = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
     .ToList()
```

If you want to continue use the overload of `GroupBy` you are currently using, you can do:

```
items.GroupBy(item => item.Order.Customer, 
              (key, group) =>  new { Customer = key, Items = group.ToList() })
     .ToList()
```

...but I personally find that less clear.

Comment: do you need the ToList() call on the group ? Would the last ToList() not be enough ?

Comment: @Joanna: According to the OP's requirements, the `Items` property of the anonymous type must be a list.

Comment: Can you please provider some assistance for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764687/how-to-use-linq-to-group-by-and-order-by-certain-column

Comment: Seems like "group by" does not work anymore in EfCore5 even in the simplest scenarios (`from la in dbContext.LawArticles group la by new { la.TenantId, la.LawArticleId } into aAgg select new { TenantId = aAgg.Key.TenantId, LawArticleId = aAgg.Key.LawArticleId, ArticleTexts = aAgg.ToList() }`, complaining "The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression ... cannot be translated"...

Comment: @Alexander I solved your problem.I did two separate operations:
1. var list = await _context.SomeTableName.AsNoTracking().ToListAsinc()
2. I use GroupBy and Select as for simple collection.
Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

you may also like this

```
var Grp = Model.GroupBy(item => item.Order.Customer)
      .Select(group => new 
        { 
             Customer = Model.First().Customer, 
             CustomerId= group.Key,  
             Orders= group.ToList() 
       })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Why is it I get `item.Field<>` and not `.Order` for example? I am using a DataTable.

Answer (score 7):

you can achive it with group join

```
var result = (from c in Customers
          join oi in OrderItems on c.Id equals oi.Order.Customer.Id into g
          Select new { customer = c, orderItems = g});
```

c is Customer and g is the customers order items.