# How to use LINQ to group by and order by certain column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

**UPDATED**: added a new column combining the Date and Time column which are string fields into DateTimeCombined column which is a DateTime field

So what the LINQ should do is group by name column and get the row for each name that has the earliest date+time. Then it should add the rest of the row for the name.

DataTable init:

```
dataT = new DataTable();
dataT.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dataT.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));
dataT.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));
dataT.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataT.Columns.Add("Place", typeof(string));
dataT.Columns.Add("DateTimeCombined", typeof(DateTime));
dataT.Columns.Add("NameMessage", typeof(string));
```

So here is the starting DataTable (which is retrieved by default):

```
Date        Time        Day     Name        Place       DateTimeCombined            NameMessage
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM        
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/29/2017   1:00PM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 1:00:00 PM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     John        Orlance     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     John        Orlance     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:15AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:15:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Mike        Atlanta     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Mike        Atlanta     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
                                Christine   Marion                                  None
                                Steph       Kearney                                 None
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Jenny       Boise       6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Jenny       Boise       6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Kelly       Ardsley     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Kelly       Ardsley     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
                                Joseph      Houston                                 None
```

The first LINQ function should be to get the earlier `DateTimeCombined` for each Name:

```
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:15AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:15:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
```

The next function should be to order that by `DateTimeCombined`:

```
- If `DateTimeCombined` is same, order first by `DateTimeCombined` and then by Name.

- If `DateTimeCombined` is same AND Name is same, order first by `DateTimeCombined` and then by Name and then by Place.


6/29/2017   8:15AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:15:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
```

The next function should be to put the rest of the rows for each name (the final DataTable should look like this):

```
6/29/2017   8:15AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:15:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Mike        Atlanta     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Mike        Atlanta     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Jenny       Boise       6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Jenny       Boise       6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM        
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/29/2017   1:00PM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 1:00:00 PM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     John        Orlance     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     John        Orlance     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:40AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:40:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:50AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:50:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:10AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 9:10:00 AM
6/29/2017   9:20AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 9:20:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:30AM      TUE     Kelly       Ardsley     6/30/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/30/2017   8:40AM      TUE     Kelly       Ardsley     6/30/2017 8:40:00 AM
```

Note: If Kelly was John (John appearing twice), for example, then the Ardsley group would go before Orlance.

What I tried so far:

```
var ordered = dataTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(en => en.Field<DateTime>("DateTimeCombined")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Update:

```
var ordered = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(en => en.Field<DateTime>("DateTimeCombined"))
            .GroupBy(en1 => en1.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();
```

Just gives me the name only.

Update:

```
  var q = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(item => item.Field<string>("Name"))
                .SelectMany(grouping => grouping.Take(1))
                .OrderBy(item => item.Field<DateTime>("CombinedDateTime"))
                .ThenBy(item => item.Field<string>("Name"))
                .ThenBy(item => item.Field<string>("Place"))
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

The above works as expected:

```
6/29/2017   8:15AM      MON     Mike        Atlanta     6/29/2017 8:15:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Jenny       Boise       6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     John        Orlance     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
6/29/2017   8:30AM      MON     Kelly       Ardsley     6/29/2017 8:30:00 AM
```

but only if i take the first row of each group (by Name). If I take all by group, the rows get all mixed up. How can I now, append the rest of `Mike's` rows after the row for Mike, append the rest of `Jenny's` rows after the row for Jenny, and so forth? Can this be done in the same LINQ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read about LINQ OrderBy and GroubBy, there is nothing difficult, you just have to chain some of OrderBy to each other and Group the result By Name

Comment: I added my code so far...

Comment: Try following : DataTable ordered = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
             .OrderBy(en => en.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
             .ThenBy(en1 => en1.Field<string>("Name")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @jdweng please see this: https://paste.ee/p/llAc6

Comment: You say group by `Name` column, then you say order by `Name` and then by `Place` - if `Name` is uniquely matched to place, the extra order is meaningless, if it is not you need to group by `Name,Place` or else you will be combining the same names from different places. What did you mean there? Also, I assume you meant if Kelly was Jenny.

Comment: Do you know why there is an extra tabbed column before some of the names?  That is causing the sorting issue.

Comment: @NetMage I updated my question to better clarify my request. Thanks.

Comment: @jdweng I have updated the DataTable. The extra column was a mistake.

Comment: Are you getting the correct results after fixing the extra column?

Comment: @jdweng The extra column came up in here but in my DataTable there is no extra column and unf no I am not. Sorry.

Comment: Do you really need separate functions to compute each step, or is one LINQ statement to get to the result all you need?

Comment: @NetMage I just put it separate to give the bigger picture. One function that does the job is all i need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the new edited question, I have this:

```
var ordered = dataT.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(en => new { Name = en.Field<string>("Name"), Place = en.Field<string>("Place") })
                   .OrderBy(eng => eng.Min(en => en.Field<DateTime>("DateTimeCombined")))
                   .ThenBy(eng => eng.Key.Name).ThenBy(eng => eng.Key.Place)
                   .SelectMany(eng => eng.OrderBy(en => en.Field<DateTime>("DateTimeCombined")), (eng, en) => en)
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I have updated my question to better clarify my request. Thanks for the feedback so far btw.

Comment: How do you get `en.en.Name` but I only get `en.Field<>`

Comment: I wasn't using a `DataTable` when we started.

Comment: @si8 updated my answer based on your improved question.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out and let you know how it went.

Comment: I did add a little more to my question, Once all the filter is done, how can I add the rows with the `NameMessage` column populated to the bottom of `ordered`?

Comment: The only issue I saw was if the date changes, it pushes the row down even though the date should be grouped by Name.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - my output exactly matches your question sample?